# Tips for debugging a Global.mpt

Tags: vba, ms-project

Short Question:

How do you debug a large Global.MPT file?

Currently my script crashes when I try to open it from the toolbar. It appears the usual, not very helpful, error message regarding the automation error. When this happens I start the individual components by pressing F5 in the VBA window and at the latest then I find the erroneous line.

Now my code runs as it should but I can't find the error that the compiler* has.
How do you deal with this problem?

*Is it a compiler error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a Solution [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/what-does-compile-vba-project-do-anyway/m-p/2898564).

I didn't know that you can compile the code manually.

It showed that i missed to remove a call for a deleted Sub.